# iOS: why second section is not displayed in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**My `.h` file** :

```
    @interface ViewPrescriptionViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

    @property(weak, nonatomic) NSArray *arr;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *menuItems;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *medicineItems;

    @end
```

**My `.m` file** :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

/* Here i send parameter to server using AFNetworking, and i got response from server ,
menu_itemes: (
        {
        bp = "000/000";
        dateTime = "05/12/2016 01:02:59 PM";
        doc =         {
            "email_id" = "batra@gmail.com";
            exception = 0;
            gender = Male;
            id = 0;
            "mobile_no" = 1234567890;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 157;
            salutation = Mr;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
        "follow_up" = 17;
        id = 37;
        medicine =         (
            "Syrup,Decold Total,20,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
            "Injection,Insulin,1,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no
        );
        patient =         {
            "email_id" = "bishtrohit@gmail.com";
            exception = 0;
            gender = Male;
            id = 0;
            "mobile_no" = 1234567890;
            name = Rohit;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            qualification = "";
            "reg_id" = 150;
            salutation = Mr;
            "wellness_id" = 290119935030;
        };
        weight = 000;
    }
)

*/

    [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Response from view Prescription server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

//        menuItems=@[@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];

        if (ResponseArray.count >0)
        {
            self.menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:ResponseArray];
            [_tableView reloadData];

            //menuItems = [ResponseArray mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"menu_itemes: %@",self.menuItems);

        }

        NSMutableArray *Myarray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=0; i<_menuItems.count; i++) {
            [Myarray addObject:[[_menuItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"medicine"]];
            NSLog(@"medicine: %@",Myarray);
        }
        if (Myarray.count>0) {

            self.medicineItems=[NSArray arrayWithArray:Myarray];
            //[_tableView reloadData];

            NSLog(@"medicine items : %@",self.medicineItems);
            NSLog(@"medicine items count : %lu",(unsigned long)self.medicineItems.count);



        }


//        _arr=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ResponseArray];
//        NSLog(@"menu_itemes: %@",_menuItems);

        [self getdata:responseObject];



    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)

     {
```

......
Then

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"S");
        //here is breakpoint

        return self.medicineItems.count;
    }


}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    { 

    NSDictionary *content = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"content = %@",content);

    ViewPrescriptionTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PatientDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.datetime setText:[content valueForKey:@"dateTime"]];
    [cell.bp setText:[content valueForKey:@"bp"]];
    [cell.weight setText:[content valueForKey:@"weight"]];
    [cell.followup setText:[content valueForKey:@"follow_up"]];


    [cell.doctorname setText:[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [cell.mobile setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"mobile_no"]]];
    [cell.email setText:[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"email_id"]];
    [cell.qualification setText:[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"qualification"]];
    [cell.wellnessid setText:[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"wellness_id"]];

    [cell.patientname setText:[[content objectForKey:@"patient"]valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [cell.patientmobile setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[content objectForKey:@"patient"]valueForKey:@"mobile_no"]]];
    [cell.patientemail setText:[[content objectForKey:@"patient"]valueForKey:@"email_id"]];
    [cell.patientwellnessid setText:[[content objectForKey:@"patient"]valueForKey:@"wellness_id"]];



    return cell;

    }
    else{

        //Cell For Medicines
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PatientDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"s");
        //here is breakpoint
        [cell.textLabel setText:[self.medicineItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

**In Storyboard**

I have taken `UITableView` on screen for this.

I have taken 1 static custom cell for this.

**What i want :**

I want two section, in first, i displayed all data which i receive from server except `medicinItems` like following image:

[image]

In second section,

I want to pass `medicinItems` in that.

but my problem is, second section is not displaped.

But i don't know how to do that..??

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Comment: is "self.medicineItems.count" returning a a number greater then 0? have you tried testing by just putting a 1 there?

Comment: yes, i tried that, but its not working

Comment: if (section == 0){ return 1; }
    else {
        NSLog(@"S");
        //here is breakpoint
        return self.medicineItems.count; }... here it comes in else ...@pflous

Comment: but in cellForRowAtIndexPath else is not called..

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Is it never hitting that breakpoint? Is section always == 0?

Comment: yes, it only work for  section==0 like showed in above image.but why it not showing 2nd section??... @pflous

Comment: can you post your console output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130537/discussion-between-suraj-sukale-and-pflous).

Comment: The code is clear that there are two sections and that section 0 has 1 row.  The length of section 1 is dependent on the array.  For section 1, if  the array has > 0 elements and the datasource is set, then cellForRow **will be called**.

Comment: length of section 1 is fixed, which is shown in above image... problem is : 2nd section is not displayed....@danh

Comment: @SurajSukale please accept answer as correct if your question as to "why second section is not displayed in UITableView?" was answered. As discussed in chat we seem to have solved this issue

Comment: The major answer meaning is that at the time you are reloading table before you finish all manipulations with data. Do `[_tableView reloadData]` after the section list array is created and do not forget for `[_tableView reloadInputViews]`;

Comment: please dont put everything on the VC.. the controller just becomes too massive :(

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload data after fetching from server and updating medicineItems:

```
if (Myarray.count>0) {
    self.medicineItems=[NSArray arrayWithArray:Myarray];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Furthermore:

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[self.medicineItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**self.medicineItems** is not an array of strings in this case so you can't set the textLabel to that object

Comment: I suggest that you move the `self.medicineItems=...` line inside the `dispatch_async` block.